# Probability of a sample proportion of defectives

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose a sample of **120** items is drawn from a population of manufactured products and the number of defective items is recorded. Prior experience has shown that the proportion of defectives is **0.05**.

a) Describe the sampling distribution of **p̂**, the proportion of defectives.

b) What is the probability that the sample proportion is less than **0.10**?

My Work:

a) $$np ≥ 5$$

because

$$ 120*0.05 =6$$

and

$$nq = 120*0.95 = 114 ≥ 5$$

therefore the sampling distribution is approximately normal distributed.

b) $$P(p̂<0.10) = P(z < (0.10-0.05)/[\sqrt{(0.05x0.95)/120)})$$

$$= P(z<0.05/0.0199) = P(z<2.5126)$$

$$ =0.9940$$

resulting in **99.4%**.

I'm not sure if I'm solving this problem properly, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks fine, though you should continue putting P( ) round your brackets in (b) i.e.. ...=  P{z<...}..

Comment: Thank you Paul! Also, thank you for the tip... I'll have to remember to include that.

Comment: It would be interesting here to compute directly with the binomial (nowadays there are plenty of programs that will do it) and perhaps compare with the Poisson approximation.  For the normal approximation $npq$ is on the small side. Maybe continuity correction would improve the quality of the estimate.